# Nested IF statement on Response Lister JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I'm using a Response Listener and JSONObject for my Login Activity. I am new to Android so I want to know if I am doing things right since my App won't work. My Login Activity should be able to identify if the user is a normal user or an Admin.

Here's my code:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListerner = new Response.Listener<String>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {

    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        boolean user = jsonResponse.getBoolean("user");
        boolean admin = jsonResponse.getBoolean("admin");

        if (admin) {
            //load Admin Activity here
        }else if (user) {
            //load User Activity here
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Incorrect username or password")
                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
};
```

My code will work if I remove one of them (admin or user). Is this correct and I am just missing something in my code? Or I can't have if and else if? Is there a better way that I can do it? Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the error you getting? also whats the behaviour when you jsonResponse.getBoolean(admin,false)

Comment: @therealprashant there's no error, it's just that the login won't work. It won't load the Activity that it's supposed to load if login is successful, and it doesn't show the error message when the inputs are invalid.

Comment: Put logs and check..if you claiming that there is no logcat output